# Find a closed surface for which $\iint_S \textbf{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$ is negative.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

$\text{div}\textbf{F} = x^2+y^2+1$. Find a closed surface for which $$\iint_S \textbf{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$$ is negative or otherwise state why it's not possible.

---

$\textbf{My attempt}$:

If $S$ and $D$ are a domain such that $\textbf{F}$ is continuous and differentiable on $S \cup D$, then by the divergence theorem:
$$\iint_S \textbf{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iiint_D  x^2+y^2+1 \ dV $$
The integral on the right is always positive and therefore there exists no such surface $S$ for which the flux integral becomes negative.

Can anyone confirm that my approach is correct? Also, what if $S \cup D$ has singularities? Can we use the extended form of the divergence theorem:
$$\iint_S \textbf{F} \cdot d\vec{S} = \iint_{S'} \textbf{F} \cdot d\vec{S} +\iiint_{D'}  x^2+y^2+1 \ dV $$
and conclude that there may exist such a surface for which $$\iint_S \textbf{F} \cdot d\vec{S} < 0$$
$S'$ encloses the singularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, *your approach to the solution of the problem is entirely correct as long as the divergence theorem holds for the domain $D$ you consider*, so your question is basically equivalent to asking for what kind of domains the Gauss-Green (divergence) theorem is true: and I'll try to answer to your question by answering to the more general one about the structure of domains for which the Gauss-Green (divergence) theorem holds in three steps.

- *The divergence theorem is true for all domains $D$ whose perimeter i.e. the measure $|\partial D|=|S|$ of their boundary is finite*: these sets are called Caccioppoli sets or sets of finite perimeter, and for them the general divergence formula
  $$
  \int\limits_D\!\operatorname{div} \mathbf{F}\, \mathrm{d}V 
  =\int\limits_{S} \mathbf{F}\,\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} =\int\limits_{S} \mathbf{F}\,\cdot\nu_D\, \mathrm{d}|\nabla\chi_D|\quad\forall\mathbf{F}\in [C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)]^n\tag{1}\label{1}
  $$
  where $\chi_D$ is the characteristic (indicator) function of the domain $D$ and $|\nabla\chi_D|$ is the (finite) total variation measure associate to its (generalized) gradient, holds true. You can find a sketch of the proof and detailed references in [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835353/domains-for-which-the-divergence-theorem-holds). Formula \eqref{1} holds irrespective of the kind of singularity $S=\partial D$ may have: there can be cusps, edges, or wedges alike. Thus, **for any positive divergence vector field $\mathbf{F}$, the flux across the boundary of any set of finite perimeter is necessarily positive**.
- However, there are also classes of sets which do not necessarily have a finite perimeter for which the divergence theorem holds. As pointed out by Ben McKay in [his answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/358667/113756) to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358606/on-which-regions-can-greens-theorem-not-be-applied), Friedrich Sauvigny  proves the general Stokes theorem for sets whose boundary has a singular part with finite capacity ([1], §1.4 pp. 30-39) and, as a corollary, a generalized Gauss-Green (divergence) theorem is demonstrated ([1], §1.5, pp. 39-49): and *the class of finite capacity sets considered by Sauvigny strictly includes the class of Caccioppoli sets*. Thus again, **for any positive divergence vector field $\mathbf{F}$, the flux across any closed boundary whose singular part has a finite capacity** (in the sense of [1]) **is necessarily positive**.
- Finally, it should be noted that [the accepted answer of Paul Siegel](https://mathoverflow.net/a/358608/113756) to the question above, goes further by conjecturing that a form of Stokes theorem in the plane may hold for every proper subset: therefore, conjecturing that his "bold" assertion is true also for higher dimensional regions, **it may be difficult if not impossible to find a set for which the flux across it of a positive divergence vector field $\mathbf{F}$ is negative, even if an infinite perimeter/capacity** (in the sense of [1]) **is allowed**.

**Final conclusions**.

As you have noted in the premise to your question, if the Gauss-Green-Divergence theorem holds for a given domain $D$ then any positive divergence vector field $\mathbf{F}$ would generate a positive flux across its boundary. Summing up, if $\operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}=x^2+y^2+1$ then

1. It is not possible to find a domain $D$ with a finite perimeter for which
   $$
   \int\limits_{S} \mathbf{F}\,\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{S} <0\label{2}\tag{2}
   $$
   since for those domains (Caccioppoli sets) the Gauss-Green (divergence) formula \eqref{1} holds
2. In the same way, it is not possible to find a domain $D$ whose singular part of the boundary has a finite capacity in the sense of [1] for which \eqref{2} holds, since even for those domains identity \eqref{1} holds.
3. And even if you consider sets of infinite perimeter whose singular part  of their boundary has an infinite capacity, it may be nevertheless be impossible for \eqref{2} to hold, since it could be possible that, in a properly generalized sense, \eqref{1} may still hold.

**Reference**

[1] Sauvigny, Friedrich, *Partial differential equations 1. Foundations and integral representations. With consideration of lectures by E. Heinz*, 2nd revised and enlarged ed. (English), Universitext, Berlin: Springer Verlag, ISBN 978-1-4471-2980-6/pbk; 978-1-4471-2981-3/ebook, pp. xv+447 (2012), [MR2907678](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2907678), [Zbl 1246.35001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1246.35001).

Comment: thanks, it was much help. sorry couldn't reply sooner.

Comment: @DubsVeer23 you are welcome, and I am glad to be of some help.